# How do I view metrics for a confluentinc/cp-kafka container?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Hi I have a Kafka container built using the image 'confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.0'.
How do I view the  metrics from the container?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an environment variable for JMX_PORT then attach a tool like jconsole or visualvm to that.

[This is mentioned in the docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/operations/monitoring.html#launching-kafka-and-zk-with-jmx-enabled), but I think it might be incorrect (at least, trying to use /jmx on Zookeeper, and the variable is only JMX_PORT and shouldn't be different in the container)

If you want to use Prometheus/Grafana, then you'll need to extend the container to add the JMX exporter

Comment: I have added the KAFKA_JMX_PORT=49999 env variable to the kafka image(not the zookeeper one) and I can build the container. How do I attach jconsole or visualvm to it?

Comment: We need the jmx host else I cant attach any monitoring tool to the jmx instance

Answer (score 0):

1. I set up Kafka using https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html#ce-docker-quickstart. This launches Kafka with JMX installed.
2. This installation provides Confluent Control Center so you can view metrics there.
   However I wanted the raw metrics exposed by JMX so I proceeded to the next steps.
3. I installed VisualVM from here https://visualvm.github.io/download.html.
   (*You can also use jconsole available in the JAVA/jdk/bin folder installed in your local m/c but I had connectivity issues running jconsole against the container JMX*.)
4. Install the VisualVM-MBeans plugin in VisualVM.
5. Add a JMX connection using the KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME:KAFKA_JMX_PORT values from your docker-compose.yml in Step 1.

Bingo you can see the metrics from Confluent Kafka running on the container!